# How to send confirmation when importing contributions

Tags: contributions, import

When importing contributions, on the 2nd page where CSV columns are linked to database fields, there is no field "send a confirmation". Is there a way to add this field (and generate a confirmation after import)? Or do we have the use another method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmation sending can't directly from import.  There ARE ways to do it, but it slows down the import considerably, so I'd recommend doing it separately.  Here are your options:

#### Bulk confirmation

- When importing, have an easy way to search for the contributions that were just imported.  Perhaps that's already possible because of your data.  If not, add a custom field "Needs confirmation" to your data, and populate that.
- Using **Find Contributions**, find the contributions you just imported.
- From the **Actions** menu, select **Receipts - print or email** and send confirmations as per the [manual receipts documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous/).
  [image]

You could also use CiviRules, but as I started to document the process I realized how complicated that would be - I definitely think the bulk confirmation above is the way to go.

Comment: thx @Jon G, this method with two steps work!